# Testing Facebook Login with Yii2 and Codeception

Tags: facebook, yii2, facebook-login, codeception

I am using the Yii2 [authclient](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/ext-authclient-index.html) extension in order to login to my page. Without logging in to the page, you are not allowed to do anyting.

Now I want to start testing with codeception, but the problem is I have to be logged in with facebook in order to test the different actions. The question is, how to do that through codeception functional test?

Answer (score 1):

this should helps
http://codeception.com/docs/modules/Facebook

And btw i would pobably would move it in acceptance tests

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on StackOverflow. Please add essential part to answer.